# EF Core 3.1.8 - Migrations Error - No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add migrations and receiving the following error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

Already tried to add the [EntityFrameworkCore.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/) package and my constructor is like

```cs
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
{

}
```

And keep throwing the error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

**Updated with database configuration**

obs:

1. User is a abstract class.
2. I'm using code first and Migrations not yet exist.

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public VenturaContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Admin> Administrators { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

**[Updated 2 - my simple solution]**

Just set my conn string on OnConfiguring method and create a empty constructor on MyContext. That was enough for what was creating.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=KONOHA; Database=my_database; User Id=user; password=********; MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            }

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: Have you registered your DB context?

Comment: Yes. I'm applying it com startup file on ConfigureServices method.

Comment: It would help if you share the database configuraition as an edit to the question.

Comment: I updated the post and add some observations can be important.

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? Your DB context class is named `MyContext`, but the constructor is of type `VenturaContext`. Also, db entities need to be concrete classes.

Comment:   I was trying to use a generic Context on description. Yep. VenturaContext is the real name. I just forgot to update that.

Comment: Please show the registration code in startup

Comment: Hi @Alex Santos, any updates about this case?

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu, yeah. I fixed. I just got into https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation and could undertand what's wrong. The link sugest me to create a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. But its s little sample and configure a connection string no OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) fixed. I'll edit the post. So thankx for help me what you could.

Comment: In fact, you only need to register the link string in the startup to achieve the same effect, just like the method I provided.

Comment: @AlexSantos Have you tried simply registering your context the standard way with `AddDbContext<MyContext>(...);`? From what you've provided, it sounds like you're over complicating things by adding this design time factory. If you haven't already tried the solution provided in the answer below, I'd highly recommend trying it before complicating things. `No Database Provider` means you haven't configured the provider package for whatever DB you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, PgSQL, etc.).

Comment: Yep @jandrew . The problem was solved just registering my context and setting -s ../my-project-api when applying migrations.  Thankx a lot. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/entity-framework/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.md) article.

Configure DBContext via AddDbContext:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Then in your MyContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
{
}  
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution and is the first thing I would try before adding unnecessary complexity. As far as I can tell, the debug log seems to indicate a pretty straightforward configuration error.

Comment: The problem was solved just registering my context and setting -s ../my-project-api when applying migrations. ;)